# Confused about sequelize associations One-To-Many and One-To-One unidirectional

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the follow entities:

- User (name, email, password)
- Goal (title, description)
- Photo (filename, path, contentType)
- GoalPhoto (fk_goal, fk_photo)

User hasMany Goal - It works fine. A foreign key is added to goal table
User hasOne Photo - Doesn't work.
Goal hasMany Photo on join table model GoalPhoto - Doesn't work.

The Photo hasn't any association with User and Goal, but the User and the Goal entities has a One-To-One and One-To-Many respectively. Photo doesn't belongs to any model.

When i put User.hasOne(Photo) it creates the foreign key in Photo table, but i want just a foreignKey in User (fk_photo).
When i put Goal.hasMany(Photo, { as: 'photos', joinTableModel: GoalPhoto, foreignKey: 'fk_goal' }) it creates the foreign key in Photo table, but i want a JoinTable with Goal and Photo foreign keys.

How can i solve that ?

Answer (score 1):

Create foreign key (photo_id) in User table:

```
User = sequelize.define('User', {});
Photo = sequelize.define('Photo', {});
Photo.hasOne(User);
User.belongsTo(Photo);
```

Create JoinTable:

```
GoalPhoto = sequelize.define('GoalPhoto', {});
Goal.hasMany(Photo, {through: GoalPhoto});
Photo.hasMany(Goal, {through: GoalPhoto});
```

Comment: yes, it works but it sounds a bit strange because photo doesn't have a user, but a user has one photo.

Comment: http://sequelizejs.com/docs/latest/associations#block-14-line-22
you can make this:
photo_id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, references: "Photo", referencesKey: "id" }